# How to make YOLO output to the input for another program?

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

I am new in this field. I am using YOLOv5 for custom object detection. It is successfully implemented. Now, I further want to use the output of YOLOv5 for another input. Actually, I want to make program which will speak to wear mask if the person has not put on the mask. The classes are: 'with_mask' and 'without_mask'. I do not have any idea how to do this. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you implemented YOLOv5 so you have to check the part with `pred` by yourself...

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
  
mytext = 'Pls wear mask'
language = 'en'
myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)
  
myobj.save("mask.mp3")
 

if pred["label"] == "without_mask":
   os.system("mpg321 mask.mp3")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am not quite sure how and where should I use the code you provided. I used the YOLOv5 model given by ultralytics and trained it for custom dataset. I did not make any other changes. So, in which part of detect.py file should I use this code? Thank you in advance